# How to rename a column and change its type by migration same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `general_exams` table, I have a column named `semester`, type is `string`. Now I want to change its name to `semester_id`, type is `integer`. I have read about migration and it has available transformations:

- rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name): Renames a column but keeps the type and content.
- change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options): Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.

So, I create my migration file like this:

```
class RenameSemesterFromGeneralExams < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    rename_column :general_exams, :semester, :semester_id
    change_column :general_exams, :semester_id, :integer
  end
end
```

But, when I run `rake db:migrate`, it has error:

```
==  RenameSemesterFromGeneralExams: migrating =================================
-- rename_column(:general_exams, :semester, :semester_id)
   -> 0.0572s
-- change_column(:general_exams, :semester_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "semester_id" cannot be cast to type integer
: ALTER TABLE "general_exams" ALTER COLUMN "semester_id" TYPE integer
```

In my table GeneralExam, I destroyed all data.
So, anyone can tell me how can I do that? Or I must create two migration files?

Comment: This question is actually really helpful because, besides the error in it, it specifies exactly how to change a column name and type in the question itself!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the `semester` contains data that cannot be converted to `integers`. That's why you get a cast error.

I suspect you need to do more work to make this work as the only thing that comes to mind is removing the column and creating a new one with the correct values.

But you can simply remove_column and then add_column in one migration. That should work flawlessly.

I'd also suggest you only add_column first, then do the mapping process where you map the old `semester` value onto the new `semester_id` and then drop the column.

Keep in mind that you can do ActiveRecord manipulations inside your migration. So you can put that code in there.

Comment: I destroyed all data in table GeneralExam. If I find no way to do that same time, I will create 2 migration, but I think it's not convenient. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with some more details

Comment: I don't need old data of semester column. So remove_column or add_column first maybe not a problem. I will do this way, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

This works as of Rails 4

```
def change
  rename_column :general_exams, :semester, :semester_id
  change_column :general_exams, :semester_id, :integer
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help

```
class ModifyColumnTables 
  def change
    remove_column :posts, :old_column
    add_column :posts, :new_column, :type_of_column
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because there is existing data in the tables (or default values, perhaps ..) that PG doesn't know how to convert from string to integer. Either get rid of the data or tell PG how you want to convert it, using PG specific SQL (I think you'll want `USING`) and `execute` migration command. See Rails guides on migrations.

Comment: I destroyed all data in that table. You mean I should using up and down?

Comment: If you've destroyed all the data, then the only thing I can think of is that the column might have a default value (which can't be converted to integer). I'm not a PG expect.

Comment: I don't set default value for that column, I'm also not understand why I can not change type when column has not value. So I had to choose the other way. Lol,  I'm also not any expert, I'm still only student :))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one migration. But this does not always work and you may get an error, especially when converting a column from boolean type to integer type, or string type to integer type, **unless you are specific how this data will be converted**.

So you have a column in the `general_exams` table called `semester` and it's a string. You want to rename it to `semester_id` and you want to change it's type to integer.

Before you do any of this make sure you have your work committed to git, so you can always reset to your older commit and start fresh without loosing your work.

**In your terminal run**

```
rails g migration rename_the_column_semester_to_semester_id
```

This will generate a migration for you. Now open your migration file.

```
db/migrate/20210xxx_rename_the_column_semester_to_semester_id.rb
```

**It will look like this:**

```
class RenameTheColumnSemesterToSemesterID < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

**Inside the change method, make your file look like this.**

```
class RenameTheColumnSemesterToSemesterID < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :general_exams, :semester, :semester_id
    change_column :general_exams, :semester_id, :integer, using: 'semester_id::integer'
  end
end
```

**Alternatively you can do this:**

```
class RenameTheColumnSemesterToSemesterID < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :general_exams, :semester, :semester_id
    change_column :general_exams, :semester_id, 'integer USING CAST(semester_id AS integer)'
  end
end
```

**Note Important:**
The above will work only if your column does NOT have a default value in your table. This is important because if you've already set a default value to your column, you'll still get an error like `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  default for column "semester_id" cannot be cast automatically to semester integer` PG will complain that your semester column already has a default value. In this case, you will need to drop the default value after you rename the column and set a new default value.

```
class RenameTheColumnSemesterToSemesterID < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :general_exams, :semester, :semester_id
    execute "ALTER TABLE general_exams ALTER semester_id DROP DEFAULT;"
    change_column :general_exams, :semester_id, :integer, using: 'semester_id::integer', default: 1
  end
end
```

of-course you can set whatever default value you want, in case you are enumerating in your model from 0, 1, 2 or whatever.

Save your migration. and run

```
rails db:migrate
```