# rename_column and change_column in one for by active record migration

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, migration

I have to rename one column of the column of table `a` and change it's datatype. I am currently doing as following:

```
class RenameIdFromA < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :a, :a_id, :id
    change_column :a, :id, :string, :limit => 50
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do in one go?? something like

```
    rename_and_change_column :a, :a_id, :id, :string, :limit => 50
```

As, it can be done in `MySQL` in one go, by following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `a` CHANGE `a_id` `id` varchar(50) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not out of box as I know of. But I can't se any problem with your current solution. It's more clear then the other one you suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a column and change its type by migration same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470670/how-to-rename-a-column-and-change-its-type-by-migration-same-time)

Comment: That question doesn't answer the question.

@aross: It will help in the cases, where table has too much data and this migration will run two queries, which will take double the time, as we know we can do this in one query it self.

Comment: Then you could use `execute` to run the SQL as is. And if you would like to still support other databases you can check your database adapter with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name` and if the condition does not match your supported database engines you can use `rename_column` and `change_column` instead. (I creaded an answer with example.)

Answer (score 1):

You can run SQL as is with `execute` and then fallback to default methods if someone is using another database engine then the one you support.

```
class RenameIdFromA < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name =~ /mysql/i
      execute "ALTER TABLE `a` CHANGE `a_id` `id` varchar(50) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL"
    else
      rename_column :a, :a_id, :id
      change_column :a, :id, :string, :limit => 50
    end
  end
end
```